# How to install an ATI 3650 video driver on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, ati, radeon

I have a fresh Ubuntu 12.10 x86_64 installation but I can't find a way to install a specific video driver for the ATI 3650 video board.
Can't find restricted drivers in Unity and the AMD ATI legacy driver complains about "missing tools" during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Either download the dirver from AMD's website, or enable restricted drivers (search "restricted drivers" in Unity).